# jQuery (or JS) - How to get only elements that are certain colour from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

I'm making some checklists that are interactive.

One of the things they do is turn a header a different colour if they are all checked, like this:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
if(($(this).attr('name'))=="check1"){
    maxchecked1 = $('[name="check1"]').length;
    curchecked1 = $('[name="check1"]:checked').length;
    console.log("First check"+curchecked1+"/"+maxchecked1);
    if(maxchecked1==curchecked1){
        console.log("all checked");
        $("#head1 a").addClass('ccomplete');
    }else{
        $("#head1 a").removeClass('ccomplete');
    }
}
```

CSS is

```
 .ccomplete{
    background:#66BC29 !important;
  }
```

This works fine.

What I also want to do is do the same test, but on the elements that change colour so I can signal when ALL the checklists are complete.

What I need to do it this

```
var heads_done  = $(".checkhead a").css("background-color" , "#66BC29");
var heads_total = $(".checkhead a").length;
```

and then compare heads_done with heads_total.

But that first line is incorrect and I can't work out how to do it. What I need is the number of items in the array .checkhead[] (which, like check1 is an array of elements) that have the new color.

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking for a color is not reliable as browsers don't return the hex value most of the time, and right now you're setting the color, not getting it, but check for the class instead

```
var heads_done  = $(".checkhead a.ccomplete").length;
var heads_total = $(".checkhead a").length;

if (heads_done == heads_total) alert('all done')
```

Comment: Brilliantly simple and made me feel silly! It works great. Thanks!